# Proving finite Union of Z-sets in $Y$ is a Z-set.

Tags: general-topology

> **Definition:**  Let $Y$ be a metric space and  $A\subseteq Y$  a closed subset. We say  $A$ is a Z-set in $Y$ if for every  $\epsilon>0$ there exist a continous mapping $f_{\epsilon}:Y\longrightarrow Y\setminus A $ such that $ d\left(f_{e}(y),y\right)<\epsilon$  for all $y\in Y$.
>
> **Proposition:** Suppose $Y$ is metric compact  If $A_1,A_2,\cdots,A_n$  are Z-sets in $Y$, prove $A=A_1\cup A_2\cup \cdots\cup A_n$ is a Z-set in $Y$.

I was trying to prove just for the case $n=2$ i.e  if $A_1, A_2$ are Z-sets then $A_1\cup A_2$  is a Z-set in $Y$  by defining $f=f_2\circ f_1$  where $f_2$ is the $\epsilon$ mapping for  $A_2$ and  $f_1$ is the $\epsilon$ mapping for  $A_1$.  It is clear that $f$is continous. Now I need to prove $f:Y\longrightarrow Y\setminus (A_1\cup A_2)$. Since  $f=f_2\circ f_1$ then $f(x)=f_2( f_1(x))$ and by hypothesis $f_1(x) \in Y\setminus A_1$ but im stuck proving that since $f_1(x) \in Y\setminus A_1$ and $f_2$ is a $\epsilon$ mapping then $f_2( f_1(x)) \in Y\setminus (A_1\cup A_2)$.

Any insight would be helpful, thanks.

Comment: Did you use compactness?

Comment: Not yet, also from the hypothesys one could use that a compact metric space is totally bounded but Im not sure how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You realized that you can prove it inductively. The key is in fact the case $n = 2$. Since $Y$ is compact, the disjoint sets $A_1$ and $f_1(Y)$ (which are compact) have a distance $r_1 > 0$. Let $\delta = \min (r_1,\epsilon/2)$ and let $f_i : Y \to Y$ be $\delta$-maps such that $f_i(Y) \subset Y \setminus A_i$. What can be said about $f = f_2 \circ f_1$? It is certainly a continuous map such that
$d(f(y), y) = d(f_2(f_1(y), y) \le d(f_2(f_1(y), f_1(y)) + d(f_1(y), y) < \epsilon$. Clearly $f(y) \notin A_2$. For $y \in Y, a \in A_1$ you get
$$r_1 \le d(f_1(y),a) \le d(f_1(y), f_2(f_1(y)) + d(f_2(f_1(y)),a ), $$
thus
$$d(f_2(f_1(y)),a ) \ge r_1 - d(f_1(y), f_2(f_1(y)) > r_1 - \delta > 0 .$$
Therefore $f(y) \notin A_1$.

Comment: So $r_1$ is the distance using Hausdorff metric, right?

Comment: In any metric space $(X,d)$ we can define $d(M,N) = \inf \{d(m,n) \mid m \in M, n \in N \}$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance. This is not a metric, but we have $d(M,N) > 0$ if $M \cap N = \emptyset$ and one of $M,N$ is compact and the other is closed